# trying to convert mp3 to wav

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyaudio

I am trying to convert mp3 file to wav format using pyaudio but getting an error
My code

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("v1.mp3")
sound.export("a.wav", format="wav")
```

and I am getting error in line 2 as follow

> CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

b"ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609\n  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv\n  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100\n  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100\n  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101\n  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100\n  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101\n  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0\n  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101\n  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101\n  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100\n[mp3 @ 0x2446020] Header missing\n    Last message repeated 1045 times\n[mp3 @ 0x243d060] decoding for stream 0 failed\n[mp3 @ 0x243d060] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size\nConsider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options\nv1.mp3: could not find codec parameters\nInput #0, mp3, from 'v1.mp3':\n  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A\n    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p\n[abuffer @ 0x2449660] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+09]\n    Last message repeated 3 times\n[abuffer @ 0x2449660] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0.\n[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x2449540] Error applying options to the filter.\nError opening filters!\n"

Comment: Upgrade your ffmpeg or provide a link to the input file that fails.

Comment: its just a mp3 file downloaded using youtube-dl.